# Passing struct pointer to function in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm having a problem with passing a pointer to a struct to a function. My code is essentially what is shown below. After calling modify_item in the main function, stuff == NULL. I want stuff to be a pointer to an item struct with element equal to 5. What am I doing wrong?

```
void modify_item(struct item *s){
   struct item *retVal = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
   retVal->element = 5;
   s = retVal;
}

int main(){
   struct item *stuff = NULL;
   modify_item(stuff); //After this call, stuff == NULL, why?
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because you are passing the pointer **by value**.  The function operates on a copy of the pointer, and never modifies the original.

Either pass a pointer to the pointer (i.e. a `struct item **`), or instead have the function return the pointer.

Comment: Are we not passing the pointer by value in the code below posted by STS Balaji? Does that code work only because we are passing the pointer address (i.e. value) because it's allocated on heap?

Answer (score 33):

```
void modify_item(struct item **s){
   struct item *retVal = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
   retVal->element = 5;
   *s = retVal;
}

int main(){
   struct item *stuff = NULL;
   modify_item(&stuff);
```

or

```
struct item *modify_item(void){
   struct item *retVal = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
   retVal->element = 5;
   return retVal;
}

int main(){
   struct item *stuff = NULL;
   stuff = modify_item();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to modify your code like below if the function 'modify_item' intends to change member of structure which is passed as argument.

```
void modify_item(struct item *s){
   s->element = 5;
}

int main(){
   struct item *stuff = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
   modify_item(stuff); 
}
```

Comment: This is a very good third alternative to what Doug C mentioned above.