# Unable to load Images with SFML and SDL?

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl, sfml

For the sake of simplicity, I wanted to create my own function for the project that I'm currently working on. Unfortunately, it kept on closing After error checking, I found out that it's the fault of it being able not to load anything from it, here's the functions:

```
//SDL
void IMG_HANDLER::loadImage(const char * file, SDL_Surface *imgSRC)
{
    imgSRC = SDL_LoadBMP(file);

    if (imgSRC == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't load IMG \n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
}


void IMG_HANDLER::SetImage(int x, int y, const char *file, SDL_Surface *dest, SDL_Surface *imgSRC)
{

loadImage(file, imgSRC);
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x=x;
    offset.y=y;


    SDL_BlitSurface(imgSRC,NULL,dest, &offset);

}

//SFML

bool SpriteLoad::LoadSprite(std::string filename)
{
    if (!Image.LoadFromFile(filename.c_str()))
    {
        printf("Can't load image file", stderr);

        exit(1);
        return false;
    }
    Sprite.SetImage(Image);
    return true;
}
```

I'm pretty confused by it, especially when the code compiled perfectly. How do I fix this?

Comment: *I'm pretty confused by it, especially when the code compiled perfectly* If only all code worked just because it compiled...

Comment: Haha, true. I'm still new to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the SFML code for the moment, I think one problem is

```
//SDL
void IMG_HANDLER::loadImage(const char * file, SDL_Surface *imgSRC)
{
    imgSRC = SDL_LoadBMP(file);

    if (imgSRC == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't load IMG \n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The value for `imgSRC` never leaves `loadImage`. You might want to make `imgSRC` a reference instead, or return the value from `loadImage`. That is:

```
void IMG_HANDLER::loadImage(const char * file, SDL_Surface* &imgSRC)
```

or:

```
SDL_Surface *IMG_HANDLER::loadImage(const char * file)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066709/passing-struct-pointer-to-function-in-c) was asked recently, and should explain the behaviour.

As far as both of them not working though, you might want to check your image file is in the appropriate format.

Comment: Quick question, can I put a class function in a array?                                                   Like:                                                                image[0] = prompt_img.loadImage("image.bmp");

Comment: @JanEstra You can put the return value into an array, so if `loadImage` returned an image you'd use the result like any other variable. If you want to put *the function itself* into an array, you can do that as well (the type of the array is just a function pointer) and if you want to put *the action of function* into an array you can use [functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B).