# function, linked list. copying one linked list to another

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote this function:

```
void something(struct node* head1, struct node* head2)
{
    statement 1 .......
    statement 2 .......
    so on.........
    // Want to make list2 (head1) be the same as list1 (head1):
    head2=head1
}
```

But this doesn't change `head2`. It does in the function but not once it gets back to the main program, why?

Comment: how are you calling the "something" function?

Comment: You'll get better responses if you tag your question with the language used.  Looks like C from the code sample alone.

Comment: If this is C: you can't assign the actual values and expect they will change. You *can* change the values pointed to. Thus, you can't change the pointers `head1` or `head2`, but you can change the structs they point to.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066709/passing-struct-pointer-to-function-in-c

Comment: Please post more of your code, such as the `node` struct.  We can't give a complete answer without knowing what you intend this snippet to actually do.

Comment: your Question is not clear , in your question heading it seems you want to copy one linked list into another (means both should hold same info), but from Question description it seems you just want head1 and head2 be the same means they should point to the same linked list, make it clear what you want , You will get the Ans.

Comment: If you want to represent a second linked list with all the nodes the same as the first, just point a  pointer to the head of the first one...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want head1 and head2 both should point to the same linked list , the problem with your code is that you are passing parameter as call by value that is why it is not reflecting out side the function you need to pass parameter by Call By Pointer(Reference). 
Try this way

```
struct Node
{
int info;
Node *next;   
}

main{
Node * head1,*head2;

// call like this

something(&head1,&head2);

}

something(Node **temphead1, Node **temphead2){

//here you can use 

//(*temphead1)

//and 

//(*temphead2)

//to perform operation 

//for example you can display list item

while((*temphead1)!=null){

printf("%d",(*temphead1)->info);

(*temphead1)=(*temphead1)->next;
}

while((*temphead2)!=null){

printf("%d",(*temphead2)->info);

(*temphead2)=(*temphead2)->next;

}
// below line will do what you were looking for

(*temphead2)=(*temphead1);

// now you can check head1 =head2 

}
```