# C - Pass structure pointer VS integer pointer to functions

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

```
void main(){
 int a = 100;
 int* pa = &a;
 *pa = 999;
}
```

The above code will make the value of a to 999. But why not the pointers to structures treated the same way?

```
struct node* head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head -> data = 6;
head -> next = NULL;
```

Why can we not use `*head -> data = 6`? And why passing `someMethod(pa)` is pass by reference and `someMethod(head)` is pass by value? [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066709/passing-struct-pointer-to-function-in-c)

Comment: Umm... Both are passing pointers ("references") here. You can change what they point to (the `int` or `struct`), but with a double pointer, you can't change where they point. So your second question is nonsensical. Your first question basically misunderstands the purpose of `->`, which is to dereference and lookup an attribute in a single operator. You could always do `(*head).data = 6;` if you want to see the `*` for dereferencing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger do you mean -- *but with a double pointer, you **can** change where they point*?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Oops. Pretty sure I meant to type *but **without** a double pointer...*. Same idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why can we not use `*head -> data = 6`?

Because `->` is a dereference operator that *replaces* the asterisk `*`. You can rewrite with an asterisk, too

```
(*head).data = 6
```

You need parentheses because [dot has higher precedence than indirection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Operator `->` has been introduced to make indirection more readable in case of pointers to `struct`s.

> why passing `someMethod(pa)` is pass by reference and `someMethod(head)` is pass by value?

It's all pass by value, because pointers are passed by value, too. Passing a pointer lets you reference the original variable and modify it, but the pointer itself is copied.

Answer (score 1):

First question's answer, you have got already.
For second Question, Consider three variables, A,B,C where A & C are integer Variables and B is a integer Pointer. Variable names, their values and address(assumed to see a memory map)
 has been shown in picture.
[image: See variables, their names, values and address]

see this code

```
void fun(int *b,int *c)
{
    printf("\nfun %d",*b);
    b=c;
}
void fun1(int **b, int *c)
{
        printf("\nfun1 %d",**b);
    *b=c;
}
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int c=200;
    int *b=&a;
    printf("\n %d %d %d",a,*b,c);
    fun(b,&c);
    printf("\n %d %d %d",a,*b,c);
    fun1(&b,&c);
    printf("\n %d %d %d",a,*b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

In `main()`,a & c are local integer **Variables**, having different data and b is a integer **pointer**. We are calling function `fun()` like this,

```
 fun(b,&c);
```

Since, b is a pointer so, we are **passing the value** of b i.e address of a  (1000).
so if we modify the  b inside function `fun()`, that change will reflect inside the `fun()` only.
Now we call the function `fun1()`,

```
 fun1(&b,&c)
```

Here, we are passing the address of b i.e (3000). so, when we modify the b inside the `fun1()` , we see the reflection in `main()` as well.

so, passing by value means, we want to use values **without modifying** the original pointer present in calling function( `main()` ). but we pass by reference, when we need any significant change which should **reflect** in our calling function( `main()` ) itself.
 I hope, this clears the doubt.